# VLC: Take Snapshot of multiple Video Streams in a single MKV

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, matroska

I have a single MKV File with multiple Video Streams included. While playing with VLC, all of the Video Streams are shown simultaneously, each in a different Window, as expected. Now i want to take a snapshot creating an Image for each of these Video Streams. At the Moment when i hit "Take Snapshot" VLC only saves the Frame from the Video in the Main Window.
How can i take a Snapshot for all active Streams?

Comment: related :https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-take-batch-screenshots-or-screencaps-in-VLC-Media-Player

Comment: I don't see how that is related to my question. I want to take a single Snapshot of all active Windows not making Batch Snapshots...